# Change table row colour on condition in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html-table

I'm creating multiple tables by date and I want my html table rows to be a different colour depending on a number of conditions. With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757680/rails-using-css-on-some-condition) I tried out the following in my shift view:

```
<% (Date.current - 6.months..Date.current + 6.months).each do |date|%>
  <% if !Shift.where(date: date).blank? %>
    <% @shifts = LaunchShift.where(date: date).all.order(start_time: :asc, booked: :desc) %>
    <h2><%= date.strftime('%e %b %Y') %></h2>

    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>...</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <% @shifts.each_with_index do |shift, index| %>
        <% if shift.booked? %>
            <% @booker = Member.find(shift.booked_by) %> 
        <% end %>
        <tbody>

        <% if shift.booked? %> <---Trying this for changing colour
            <tr style="background-color:red">
        <% else %>
            <tr>
        <% end %>
        <td><%= shift.start_time.strftime("%H:%M") %></td>
        <% if shift.booked? %>      
          <td>Booked</td>
          <td><%= link_to @booker.name, member_path(@booker) %></td>
        <% else %>
          <td>Free</td>
          <td></td>
        <% end %>
        [...]
          </tr>
        </tbody>
  <% end %>
</table>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

But only some of the rows marked as booked are red, though the shifts.booked? returns as True. Does this approach work differently than I think it does? Is there a better way to do this that that doesn't use JS/JQuery (Don't know those). Any advice?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like

```
.booked{
  background-color: red;
}

.available{
  background-color: grey;
}

<tr class="<%= shift.booked? ? 'booked' : 'available' %>">
</tr>
```

If shift is booked then booked class will apply otherwise available class will apply using ternary operator.

Comment: Thank you, this is a better way. But the problem remains that the logic goes wrong somewhere. Not all booked shifts are red and not all available shifts are grey. Could this have anything to do with the loop within a loop for creating the tables? The data is correctly displayed but somehow the if statement does not always work. Any ideas?

Comment: @SKR if data is displaying correct then if condition should be correct,
Idea is that if shift is booked then red color will apply otherwise grey color will apply to <tr></tr>

Comment: By "not working" I mean that a shift can be booked, but the row is not coloured. In the table the data is correct (using booked? several times and it works). The wierd thing is that _some_ rows get correct colour, but not all. I guess this is no longer a css problem but a logic problem, and I should make a new question. Thank you for taking time to look!

Answer (score 1):

@ashvin's solution is fine but it would be nice to go one step farther and put the ternary operator into a helper method, thereby keeping your view free of logic. e.g.

```
<tr class="<%= booked_class(shift) %>">
```

create a shift_helper.rb file in the helpers folder

```
module ShiftHelper
  def booked_class(shift)
    shift.booked? ? "booked" : "available"
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes this is also better way to apply class on condition base.